# Jest + RTL: how to get the element size?

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs, frontend, react-testing-library

I have a fixed header element with height of 300px on top, but when the user scrolls, it changes your height to 180px. I need to test it with Jest but when I try to get the element size with (element).offsetHeight, Jest returns zero.

Any ideas to test this feature?

`expect(HeaderElement.offsetHeight). toBeLessThanOrEqual(180);`